# Can I put a morph map "alias" in a laravel eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a MyModelClass $property I can set or an Eloquent\Model method I can override to morph map into a different namespace?  (Not in AppServiceProvider, right on the model please.)

The ugly details if you care to know...
I like to separate multiple models in different namespaces.  For example I might have App\Access\User, App\Searchable\User, and App\Orm\User.  My problem is, if an App\Orm\User is phonable by way of morph to/from a phone_numbers table (phonable_type, phonable_id) ~ then phonable_type would be App\Orm\User and therefore App\Searchable\User can't morph to the phone number and/or I can't search for a user by morphing from phone numbers.

If I can't alias my way between namespaces in the query builder, then I've got a solution in mind... just not as pretty.

Comment: I don't fully get the question. The namespace of a class has nothing special to do with Eloquent and models, you can simply set it at the top of a model file. This way you can have multiple models with the same name in different namespaces. Although I discourage you to use this extensively, because it may introduce bugs when you don't pay attention when importing classes.

Comment: In a morph relationship, the *_type table column values are all namespaced, unless you make a single unified morph map in the app service provider.

Comment: So you want the same model in different namespaces but with the same capabilities (relations, properties, etc.)?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to morph map from a model class rather than the app service provider.

Comment: The various namespaces can help, when you build with packages or have different people working on different things like the guard's user, or the billable's/payable's user.  No need to have all that mixed into one class.

Comment: The morph map is held in an associative array in `abstract class Relation`.  So it would not be possible to have multiple classes mapped to the same morph name.  Why don't you use the same class for your model and then separate your `Orm`, `Access`, and `Searchable` functionality using traits?

Comment: This comment thread focussed on the namespacing is not really addressing my question.  If you don't re-use names in different namespaces ... why have namespaces?  Anyway, they're not all going in the same namespace and they're not all going in traits because the packages need tests and the methods are not all static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out...  I was able to overload the newMorphMany and change App\Search\Loan for App\Orm\Loan which is attached to the remarks (comments) table.

```
protected function newMorphMany(Builder $query, Model $parent, $type, $id, $localKey)
    {
    //switch namespaces
    $parent = new \App\Orm\Loan();
    return parent::newMorphMany($query, $parent, $type, $id, $localKey);
    }
```

Comment: I think another way to do this would be to move the morphmap to a config file, then update the config on the fly.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Will do, would have done it back when I posed it, but it said I had to wait 2 days - then I forgot. You appear to have lots of points.  If you're tied in with the moderators, perhaps you could pass that along.